# If the image of an orthonormal basis is bounded, is the linear operator also bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am looking to either prove or disprove that if a linear operator is bounded on an orthonormal basis of a (separable) Hilbert space, the operator is itself bounded.

Expanding each $x$ according to the orthonormal basis $\left\{e_{j}\right\}$ and using $\left\|Te_j \right\| \leq K, \forall j \in \mathbb{N} $  what I have got so far is

\begin{align} \left\|Tx \right\|^2 = \left\| \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle x,e_i \rangle Te_i \right\|^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \langle x,e_j \rangle  \langle x,e_j \rangle \langle Te_i, Te_j \rangle \\ &\leq K^2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i \rangle \right)^2  \end{align}

but we would like to have is $\left\|T_x \right\|^2 \leq C \left\|x\right|^2$, where $\left\| x \right\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty | \langle x, e_i \rangle|^2 $ by Bessel's equality. I'm wondering then, is there another way to prove the statement or is it perhaps that the statement is untrue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As indicated by Jochen below, the answer is no. However, if $A : H\to H$ and you replace $\|Ae_n\|$ being bounded by the requirement that each of the linear functionals $x\mapsto\langle Ax,e_n\rangle$ is bounded (which means that $e_n\in dom\,A^*$), then $A$ is bounded since then $A^*$ is densely defined. This is equivalent to $A$ being closable. But as $dom\,A = H$, $A$ is bounded by the closed graph theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Extend $\{e_i: i\in\mathbb N\}$ to a HAMEL basis $B$ such that $\|b\|\le 1$ for all $b\in B$ and define $f:B\to \mathbb R$ so that $f(e_i)=1$ but $f$ is unbounded and extend it to a linear map on the whole space. This extension isn't continuous.

Comment: But does there exist an extension that is continuous?

Comment: @mr_e_man: Consider the sequence $x_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} e_i$.  This sequence converges in $H$ by Bessel's inequality and completeness (since $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} < \infty$).  But $f(x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ which diverges, and therefore $f$ cannot be continuous.

Answer (score 4):

We have a orthonormal sequence $(e_n)$ such that
$$
x =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n \quad \forall x\in H
$$
and the existence of $K>0$ such that
$$
\|Te_n\|_H \le K \quad \forall n.
$$ 
Moreover, $T:H\to H$ is linear, and it remains to prove continuity.
As the counter-example in the other answer shows this is not possible. 
I will show that under an additional assumption we can get continuity.

Now let us take $x$ such that
$$
x =  \sum_{n=1}^N \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
for some (finite) $N$. By linearity
$$
Tx= \sum_{n=1}^N \langle x,e_n\rangle T e_n
$$
and by orthonormality for $y\in H$
$$
|\langle Tx,y\rangle| \le  \sum_{n=1}^N \langle x,e_n\rangle \langle Te_n,y\rangle\le \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}
\left(\sum_{n=1}^N |\langle Te_n,y\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
\le \|x\| \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |\langle Te_n,y\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$
This shows by using this identity twice
$$
\|Tx\|^2 
\le \|x\| \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |\langle Te_n,Tx\rangle|^2 \right)^{1/2}\\
\le \|x\|^2 \left(\sum_{n,m=1}^N |\langle Te_n,Te_m\rangle|^2 \right)^{1/2}.
$$
Now if in addition to the original assumptions we would have
$$
\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty |\langle Te_n,Te_m\rangle|^2<\infty
$$
then this proves that $T$ is bounded on the dense subspace $span(e_n,n\in \mathbb N)$. Hence it can be uniquely extended to a continuous operator on the whole space.

My assumption above yields to a so-called Hilbert-Schmidt operator. The assumption is much too strong, as the example $T=I$ shows.

Comment: If you make the assumption that $T$ is Hilbert-Schmidt, you don't need to go through all these steps. The operator would be automatically compact, hence bounded.

Comment: I do not assume Hilbert-Schmidt. I used an assumption on the $Te_n$'s which make $T$ continuous, but then also Hilbert-Schmidt.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not saying it is, but this *could be* (in fact *should be!*) a homework question.

Here's an explicit counterexample: for each $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$, define

$$T(e_n) = u_n = n^{-1/2} (e_1 + e_2 + \cdots + e_n).$$

Then $\|u_n\| = 1$, and we have defined a linear operator $T$ on the finite linear span of the orthonormal basis $(e_n)$, with $\|T(e_n)\|=1$.

Now consider

$$T(u_n) = n^{-1/2} \sum_{j=1}^n a(j,n)e_j$$

for some coefficients $a(j,n) \geq 0$, which we must estimate. Thus

$$ \|T(u_n)\| = n^{-1/2} \left( \sum_{j=1}^n |a(j,n)|^2 \right)^{1/2}.$$

If you carefully consider what happens when $j \leq n/2$ and do some estimates, you should be able to show (*using integration estimates, or just elementary algebra and induction - another great exercise!*) that $a(j,n) \geq a(n/2, n) \geq An^{1/2}$ for some fixed $A>0$ and all even $n$, say.

Putting it back in gives

$$ \|T(u_n)\| \geq An^{-1/2} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n/2} n \right)^{1/2} \geq Bn^{1/2} $$

for all even $n$, and some fixed $B>0$ (actually for odd $n$ also if you think about it).

Thus we have an *explicit* operator $T$ and *explicit* vectors $u_n$ such that $\|u_n\| = 1$ but $\|T(u_n)\| \rightarrow +\infty$, which shows that $T$ is unbounded.

**Note:** we've shown that $T$ is unbounded on a particular dense but non-closed linear subspace, the set of all finite linear combinations of $(e_j)$. Thus, obviously $T$ cannot be extended to a bounded linear operator on the *whole* space. We have *not* given an explicit example of an unbounded operator on the *whole space*. In fact, such examples are *impossible to give*: some nonconstructive axioms such as the axiom of choice are required (*to produce Hamel bases, etc.*), because it is *consistent* with ZF set theory that all linear operators on the whole Hilbert space (or, more generally, a Banach space, or even a Frechet space) are bounded! (And thus, any unbounded linear operator on the whole space is necessarily nonconstructive within "ordinary" mathematics. So in some sense, it's actually a matter of *opinion* whether unbounded linear operators on the whole space even exist!)